# bluetooth LE startscan not showing scan results on certain API levels

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, bluetooth-lowenergy

I finally got some scanning set up on Android Studio and ran the code, but it did not work on my phone (API level 21). I tried with another phone at API level 28 and it still didn't show any scan results. Finally, I used an API level 30 phone, and it worked.

The code that I have is from [this](https://punchthrough.com/android-ble-guide/) article but even when I tested the author's source [code](https://github.com/PunchThrough/ble-starter-android), I had the same result: didn't work on API level 21, 29 and worked on 30.

The source code is made to work with API level 21 and up. So is this an issue in the phone's settings for Bluetooth? I am really confused since at least the source code should have it working with API 21+.

On both of those phones that scan results were not showing, I have tested other commercial BLE apps and all worked on the API 28 phone but almost none on my API 21 phone. The few that did work on my API 21 phone were high-production level apps like Dabble.io and ArduinoBlue.

Perhaps for older android versions, there may be some additional tweaking to do besides your usual: bleScanner.startScan()

Comment: Which permissions did you add to you manifest file?

Comment: these three: 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

I read that I should also allow access location in background for API 29 but that doesn't explain why it doesn't work for API 21